# Regex search by dictionary in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, trie

I have a large dictionary (about 10 million words and expressions). I would like to build a very fast system allowing to search the whole dictionary using * and ? masks. E.g.:

> **est**:
>
> for**est**
>
> **est**imate
>
> n**est**
>
> *k??g**:
>
> k**in**g
>
> k**ag**g**le**
>
> k**in**g**dom**

I know it could be easily solved using *trie* data structure, if I program it manually. Is there production-ready (or almost ready) for such a task in Java?

Comment: If that were in a database you could translate those queries to `like '%est%'` and `like 'k??g%' `. If you don't have that data in a db you could have a look at an in-memory db. Alternatively you could have a look at the various search engines built on top of lucene (or directly use lucene).

Comment: You may want to have a look at Apache Lucene and its fuzzy search capabilities.

Comment: not using trie data structure, but Apache Lucene is a very capable indexing and search framework

Comment: @Thomas I am using MySQL and it won't be using index for such an operation. Which makes it rather expensive.

Comment: @halileohalilei It would be an overkill to use a full text search library for dictionary lookup.

Comment: So, you are asking us for ready code? That's off-topic for stack overflow. We're here to answer questions about programming issues, not about existing tools and libraries. See the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @DenisKulagin I don't think so. What you're trying to achieve is not really a trivial task. Since you're looking for some production ready library, Lucene may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a single string that contains those 10 million words and phrases. Build the string so that there's one entry per line. That is, if "foo", "bar", and "bas" are all words, the string would be:

```
"foo\nbar\nbas\n"
```

You can then use the standard regular expression library to find all of the matches. Just make sure that your regex is anchored so that it doesn't extend beyond a newline. So if you look for the regex `"ba*"`, it will find "bar" and "bas", rather than finding "bar\nbas\n".

I *think* the default in Java regular expressions is to stop at newlines, so you might not have to do anything special. Otherwise, there are regex options that will let you specify how to handle embedded newlines in your string.

One thing to point out: when the regex engine reports that it found a match, it'll report the starting position. You'll need to back up to the start of the word (previous `\n`), and copy to the end (next `\n`).

Obviously, you'd want to build this giant dictionary string just once at startup, or whenever the dictionary changes. Whatever, you really don't want to be building it for every single search.

It's not the fastest possible solution, but it's quite likely fast enough for your purposes. It's easy to implement and easy to prove correct. It'd be a good way to get started.